# How do I play a HTTPS audio stream in MediaPlayer on Android[Nexus 5,7]

Tags: android, audio, https

Our APP has to stream music from network source. My question is why the mediaplayer play well when I play music using http stream, but I always got ERROR(1,-1004) when I use https stream source to play in some devices. **Important:**It only got this ERROR(1,-1004) in some devices, such as Nexus5, Nexus7 and Asus Fonepad 7.

Here is a snippet :

```
    String url ="http://10.0.0.45/O0$1$8I87308.mp3";

    MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    myMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        myMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        myMediaPlayer.prepareAsync(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "mp3 not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //mp3 will be started after completion of preparing...
    myMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
            player.start();
            System.out.println("onPrepared");
        }

    });
```

Comment: try prepare() instead of prepareAsync(), report back if it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it still doesn't work and I will get another exception like this: java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1